# Добавление кастомной страницы для плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

Написал класс генерации RSS для Mail.ru.

Сейчас нужно выделить отдельный адрес для доступа к этой ленте. Посмотрел мануал. Там указывается класс `wp_rewrite` для работы с ЧПУ WordPress. Пытался добавить правило, чтобы работала ссылка `/rss/mailru`. Но не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить правило, чтобы он отдавал сгенерированный контент из файла mailru.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не нужен rewrite. Сделайте так:

```
function mail_ru_rss() {
    $uri  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( '/rss/mailru' === untrailingslashit( $path ) ) {
        include 'mailru.php';
        die();
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'mail_ru_rss' );
```

Comment: Выдаёт 404 ошибку.

Comment: Ааа..  Понял. Я изначально вставил этот код в написанный плагин. И получил 404. Сейчас вставил в functions.php и он отдал мне нужный ответ. А для плагина можно как-то сделать? Плагин-то можно активировать/деактировать не влезая в код.

Comment: Так же и в плагине этот код будет работать. Вы куда-то не туда вставили.

Comment: Да, точно. Заработало. Не знаю, что это было... Вроде бы, делал тоже самое. В очередной раз, огромное Вам спасибо!